# LSTM with multiple input attributes, in keras

Tags: python, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm a quite beginner to RNN, and I'm studying on LSTM. So I'm following the tutorial [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/). The tutorial uses a input, which has only one attribute other than to the time period.

What I'm asking is how can we model if we have multiple attributes as inputs(like in regression). Note that, even if we have multiple attributes, the main attribute(which is going to predicted) is the given attribute called "number of passengers".
I really appreciate if you can post examples..

Comment: The link you posted might be an accurate example, but would be much easier for others to help you if you were actually posting some example code of what you have tried so far. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar example on the same site which i believe is what you are looking for.

https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/